# IdentityServer 4 - Multiple tab login 400 error

Tags: c#, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I have a .net core 3.1 MVC IdentityServer4 application (A tailored quickstart app provided by the guys at Idsrv) which I use for authentication against a SPA which is built using the oidc-client library and I've recently been able to replicate an issue regarding a 400 error that appears every now and then when trying to login to Identity Server.

1. Open up two separate tabs on Chrome/Firefox/Edge and navigate to the
   path of the client app on both tabs (e.g. https://localhost:5001).
   Both tabs correctly redirect to the URL of my identity server
   instance as the user has not yet logged in (https://localhost:5002).
2. Login on the 1st tab with username and password, or even an external
   OIDC client - this works fine.
3. Attempt to login on the 2nd tab with username and password
4. 400 Error occurs and after checking the logs I get the following CORS issue (which I don't really think is related):

   [15:51:29 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
   CORS request made for path: /Account/Login from origin: null but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint
5. If I click back in the browser the login page shows again, and then I can login as expected.

So to summarise, once a user has successfully logged in to the 1st tab, the 2nd tab will always throw a 400 error the first time a user tries to login to IdentityServer there. I'm really struggling to work out why this could be - and the CORS error message is a little strange too as when I click back and attempt login the 2nd time it works fine.

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "WebApp",
                ClientName = "Web App",

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                RequirePkce = true,

                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference, // This ensures tokens are revoked on logout

                RedirectUris = {
                    $"{webClientHost}/Oidc/SigninOidc",
                    $"{webClientHost}/Oidc/SilentRefresh"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { webClientHost + "/" },

                AllowedCorsOrigins = { webClientOrigin },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    IdentityServerSettings.ApiScopeName
                },

                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                AccessTokenLifetime = (int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(isAppSettings.WebAccessTokenLifetime)).TotalSeconds,
                RequireConsent = false
            }
```

Has anyone every experienced anything like this? Could it be something to do with my setup at all or is this a known flaw with the Identity Server 4 Quickstart app? I've been trying to debug, but the 400 error I experience means the debugging doesn't even hit so I'm struggling. Thanks

Comment: did your problem resolve? I got the same issue and looking for the solution.

Comment: Yes, exactly this problem. What is worse, the error also sometimes appears for the second consequent login attempt even if the browser was closed after first attempt. It seems Chrome caches something.

Answer (score 5):

For those that come here in the future  (I am using Duende Identity Server v6), I managed to work around this by adding this middleware which sends them back to the login page with the original request to get a new anti forgery token.  If they had logged in correctly the login page will flash then automatically return them to the application otherwise they can just login as normal:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using System.Net;

namespace IdentityServer
{
    public class FixAntiForgeryIssueMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly ILogger logger;
        private readonly string matchPath;

        public FixAntiForgeryIssueMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, string matchPath)
        {
            this.next = next;
            this.matchPath = matchPath;
            logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<FixAntiForgeryIssueMiddleware>(); ;
        }
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            await next.Invoke(context);
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString(matchPath)))
                {
                    if (context.Request.Form.TryGetValue("Input.ReturnUrl", out var returnUrls))
                    {
                        var returnUrl = returnUrls.FirstOrDefault();
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect(matchPath);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the Progam.cs/HostingExtensions.cs use it like this:

```
app.UseMiddleware<FixAntiForgeryIssueMiddleware>("/account/login");
```

Comment: Ingenious, works well! I think it's better then other more sophisticated solutions with token validations. I had to replace a key `Input.ReturnUrl` to just `ReturnUrl` in my case.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not related/caused by identity server rather how ASP.Net Core uses antiforgery token. This issue is similar in many cases to an issue reported on github https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2676.

In this particular instance once the user successfully logs in the application, Identity server issues a session cookie and thus the request token and antiforgery token go out of sync.

Since the preloaded login page relies on the old antiforgery token, once the request starts processing the systems throws following exception -

"Antiforgery token validation failed. "The antiforgery cookie token and request token do not match."

Here is the stack frame -

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery cookie token and request token do not match.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateTokens(HttpContext httpContext, AntiforgeryTokenSet antiforgeryTokenSet)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)

As antiforgery token validation is executed before actions, hence the authorization fails and request processing is aborted, the execution control never reaches the login code.